# Alarm manager notifications fires early

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have created an app that fires notification ata a certain time a few times throughout the day. On some devices the notifications fire late, some are on time and some come early. Is it the problem with the device or the code? I have put setExact(). Is there a problem with the API of device?thanks in advance

Comment: are you sending it from a server

Comment: Im sending it from a database, where i get the time (hour, minute) and set the second and millisecond 0

Comment: It is a local notification

Comment: if it's from a database them it could be that your server process requests slowly or the user's phone is slow or perhaps the user has internet connection problem.

Comment: The notification doesnt need internet

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: Local database SQL

Comment: I recommend you move the code to a background service so the app works even if it's closed.         https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service

Comment: if the app is closed then the notification might go off late or too early.

Comment: I will look into that thank you